# Metadescription Drupal

Tags: drupal, seo, meta-tags, meta

i did not find how can i add a metadescription in a list of pages of drupal in admin mode to improve my SEO [SEO metadescription pages list drupal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/me5pN.jpg)  ¿What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Use the metatag module to automatically generate metadescriptions or put them by hand for ranges of pages. https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag
Or is this not your question? It's not quite clear.